# Is 3.5VDC going to damage an stm32 analog input?

Tags: stm32, adc, input

I have a pressure transmitter sensor that is supplied with 5VDC and provides 0.5-3.5VDC analog value within a pressure range of 0-4bar. The system that I'll be using the sensor within, will almost never have a pressure above 3bars which gives a max. value of 2.75VDC.

Nevertheless I want to make sure that this voltage of 3.5VDC will not damage my stm32f401 analog input. According to the datasheet of the MCU the input can withstand a max voltage of 4VDC and measure a max voltage of Vref+ which in this case will be 3.3VDC. I cannot really protect the input with schottky diodes since the min. forward voltage of a schottky is 0.2V.

The input will have an RC low pass filter which means that a series resistance of ~10k will be provided. This will further limit any potential current caused by exceeding the voltage levels.

Would this be considered a stable approach?

Comment: You could always use a voltage divider to linearly scale down all voltages.

Comment: Sounds like it's okay according to the datasheet! And just in case it's not, a 10k series resistor will definitely limit any possible damage. And just in case it doesn't, you aren't expecting to get that voltage anyway. So, you're triply protected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be okay based on the absolute maximum 4V and injection current limits in Table 12 and Table 53 of the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f401re.pdf).

There are internal protection networks which shunt current from an analog input that exceeds Vdd to the supply rail. In the case of an input that is worst-case connected to the 5V rail the current could be as high as 170uA. You should make sure that's comfortably exceeded by the minimum consumption of your circuit so it can't lift the rail (assuming a typical regulator that can only source current). If you anticipate users doing worse than that (maybe there's a 12VDC or 24VAC supply nearby) then protect accordingly. From the datasheet:

[image]

By the way, using Schottky diodes, even small ones, on analog inputs can be problematic if you need to design for robust operating conditions- the leakage can easily cause large errors at elevated temperatures with 10K source resistance.

Comment: Could you explain the part on the requirement of minimum consumption of 170uA. Which circuit is this: the general circuit or maybe the analog input circuit? The MCU is powered by 3.3V LDO LVR which is connected to 5V.

Comment: So if the input is connected to 5V and Rain in the above circuit is 10K and Vdd is 3.3V there could be 170uA (ignoring Vt of the diode) as (5V-3.3V)/10K. Most LDO regulators cannot sink current so it could cause Vdd to increase out of regulation if the total current draw from the LDO (say in sleep mode) was very low.